# Cannot access object properties of fetched Json data with React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks, use-state

**I can't access the *`data`* object properties in the parent component**

After I fetch the data from the api in the child function, I receive a `json` data. Within the `.then` promise if I console log the response I get ***[object Object]***. If I console log `response.page` or `response.results[1].title` I get the expected object property, but log of `response.results` gives ***[object Object] [object Object]***.

Also I need the data in the parent component, so I put that data in fetchedData state hook, and returned it. So inside the parent component if I console log the data from the function. I get as ***[object Object]***.
And if I do `maindData.data` or `mainData.data.page`, I get an error saying ***data or page of undefined is not accessible*** unlike in the previous case where at least I was getting the property.

What could be the cause of this error? Is it because react hooks always returns an Array rather than an object? If so than what could be the solution for this ??

---

> Parent component

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios"
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import TmdbApiUrl from "./apiUrl"
import {FetchUrl} from "./fetchUrl"
import "../assets/mediaList.sass"
import Navigation from "./partials/nav";
import MediaCard from "./partials/mediaCard";


const MediaList = ()=> {
   const {generalType} = useParams();
   const {media} = useParams();
   const {page} = useParams();
   const key=process.env.API_KEY;
   const url=`${TmdbApiUrl.baseURL()}${media}/${generalType}?api_key=${key}&page=${page}`;
   const {mainData,loading,status}=FetchUrl(url);

  console.log(`#loading==>${loading}`);
  console.log(`#FetchedData==>${mainData.data}`);
  console.log(`#status==>${status}`);

  return (
    <div className="mediaList">
      <Navigation />
      <div className="list m-5 d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around">
        <MediaCard/>
        {/*{data.map(media=>(*/}
        {/*<div className="m-5">*/}
        {/*  <MediaCard*/}
        {/*      rating={true}*/}
        {/*      ratingValue={media.vote_average}*/}
        {/*      year={media.release_date}*/}
        {/*      title={media.title}*/}
        {/*      text={media.overview}/>*/}
        {/*</div>))}*/}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default MediaList
```

---

> Child function

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

export const FetchUrl=(url)=> {
  const [fetchedData,setFetchedData]=useState({mainData:null,loading:true,status:null});
  console.log(`url==>${url}`);
  useEffect(()=>{
    setFetchedData({mainData:null,loading:true,status:null});
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(response=>{
        console.log(`response==> ${response}`);
        setFetchedData({mainData:response.data,loading: false,status:response.status});
        })
      .catch((error)=> console.log(`sorry for the ${error}`));
  },[url]);
  return fetchedData;
};
```

---

> JSON data from TMDB API

```
{
data:{
  "page": 1,
  "total_results": 10000,
  "total_pages": 500,
  "results": [
    {
      "popularity": 564.69,
      "vote_count": 2822,
      "video": false,
      "poster_path": "/xBHvZcjRiWyobQ9kxBhO6B2dtRI.jpg",
      "id": 419704,
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/5BwqwxMEjeFtdknRV792Svo0K1v.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Ad Astra",
      "genre_ids": [
        18,
        878
      ],
      "title": "Ad Astra",
      "vote_average": 5.9,
      "overview": "(description..bla..bla..bla...)",
      "release_date": "2019-09-17"
    },
    {
      "popularity": 194.755,
      "vote_count": 12119,
      "video": false,
      "poster_path": "/5vHssUeVe25bMrof1HyaPyWgaP.jpg",
      "id": 245891,
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/lvjRFFyNLdaMWIMYQvoebeO1JlF.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "John Wick",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        53
      ],
      "title": "John Wick",
      "vote_average": 7.2,
      "overview": "(description..bla..bla..bla...)",
      "release_date": "2014-10-22"
    }
  ]
},
  status:200
}
```

---

Comment: yea I'am passing the URL to the child, fetching the data in the child, and returning it to the parent component. Child is just a file with FetchUrl named function in it and importing it in the parent component.

Comment: It seems that you are confused by [object Object]? This is what is displayed when you try to log an object. If you really want to see what the object contains, you do a console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)). This will convert the object to a JSON string so that you actually can see the contents of the object

Comment: i think for dinamic fetch would be better to do HOC

Comment: @ Viktor  yea I know that by doing JSON.stringify(obj) I can see the output, that Isn't the issue. I want to access the obj properties using (dot .) like obj.page, obj.data.title

Comment: @Daviti It would be better in HOC's but I want to reuse this function and imp it from a  seperate file. Also want to find the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution but using redux. If the fetched json data was huge i.e. deeply nested say for example

```
API object=A:{
             B:{ 
               C:{ 
                 D:E }
                 }
               }
```

then I would have had to put if statements for each of the deeper object keys i.e.

```
received data=A.B.(C?C:null).(D?D:null)
```

or else it would give me C or D as `undefined` and this is not an efficient solution. So then I used `mapDispatchToProps` & `mapStateToProps` from redux which dispatched the fetchAPI action and loaded the entire data before putting it into redux state.

Comment: You can also do `A?.B?.C?.D`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting data in wrong way

```
setFetchedData({data:{mainData:response.data},loading: false,status:response.status});
```

should be

```
setFetchedData({ mainData:response.data ,loading: false, status:response.status });
```

Comment: sorry  my bad... that is what I was trying to do in the first place. was just messing around to see the corresponding changes in output.

Comment: so what's the issue now?

Comment: In the child function after using hooks, I  return the data from the state. In the parent component I assign the returned data from the function to new object variables. So then if I console log `mainData.data` I get  ***[object Object]***  and JSON.stringyfy shows a string of the actual output. But the if I try to access the properties like `mainData.data.page` or `mainData.data.results` I get an error saying ***cannot access page of undefined!***

Comment: Which means you are accessing it the wrong way. Console log and then play with this to find the right property access path

Comment: The path is correct.. I made a new variable and assigned  `Object.create(mainData.data)`  to it. Then if I do `variable.page` or `variable.results` I get the correct output. But again can't access the further nested objects. Throws similar errors. Hence now I stopped using hooks and converted the parent function to a class with state and componentDidMount method. And it works fine here i.e. I can access the properties with dot notation (this.state.mainData.data.page)!  So why does this issue occurs with hooks??

Answer (score 0):

Select the position of the object in the array and then access the property. Eg:

```
User[0].name
```